# Load and start WPF app as an assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection, .net-assembly

I have a WPF application "X" I want to use it for some file loading, file processing, data processing, data learning and many other data mining stuff.

I have a data source in an external application. The application allows custom made unmanaged DLLs for custom data-mining, but I just don't like C++ as I used to. The unmanaged DLL just loads a managed DLL via COM and pass the data there.

But - the managed DLL is still just a data proxy.

From the unmanaged DLL, I know, when the data source application requests the user made libraries and when is it sending data to them - when the request is made, I want the DLL proxy to start an application defined in a configuration file, hook on it and feed it with data.

I thought reflection might be the best way of doing that.

My idea was creating a different DLL which would expose an interface. The DLL proxy would look for a public type implementing that specific interface, create its instance and then call its interface methods.

Answer (score 0):

Answered myself at the end of writing this question, I have no idea why I thought it won't work before testing it first...

> My idea was creating a different DLL which would expose an interface.
>   The DLL proxy would look for a public type implementing that specific
>   interface, create its instance and then call its interface methods.